# Service Fabric DLLHost?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

The default `ServiceManifest.xml` contains the following:

```
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>Whatever.exe</Program>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

In my "Whatever" project it also generated a `Program.cs` file that contains a `static void Main()` that does important stuff.

According to IntelliSense, I could instead have:

```
<EntryPoint>
  <DllHost>
    <ManagedAssembly>Whatever.dll</ManagedAssembly>
  </DllHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

...but what happens to my `Main()`? Do I have to substitute it somehow?

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Entry-Point Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682596(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @RemusRusanu Interesting! ...though it requires very ugly interop in C#. It looks like a really bad idea. If that's the solution, I'd rather remain with that exe that is completely useless outside Fabric.